# What does the 'this' keyword refer to in a Asp.Net Page Class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

e.g. 
this before the TextBox1 is used

```
this.TextBox1.Text
```

Comment: This is a really basic question. You should re-visit the C# / .Net basics.

Answer (score 4):

`this` is a keyword which references the current object in place.

For eg. inside a Trial class, if you have some code that says `this.Name` it basically compiles to `Trial.Name`

*Why use `this` ?*

Because at sometimes if your class makes a reference to some other class or inherits from other class that has the property with same name, you need to avoid name clash by using `this`

Comment: If I simply use TextBox1.Text.What the difference occurs.

Comment: It will work the same. Use that. As i explained, we use this to avoid name clashes if they occur

Comment: @deep if you have a local variable inside a function also called `TextBox`, `this.TextBox` would refer to the Textbox on the page and just `TextBox` to the local variable.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx), the `this` keyword refers to the current instance of the class.

`this` can be used to:

- Resolve ambiguity (if the name of a local variable is the same as the name of an instance variable)
- Improve code readability (to make clear that an instance variable, method or property is being accessed)
- Open Intellisense (typing `this.` will open up intellisense with options for the current instance)

Answer (score 0):

Using `this` keyword in a page class refers to the current instance of the object. It helps when you have to differentiate same kind of objects of a base class and inherited class.